# Need basemap with just state outlines?

Tags: qgis, data, basemap

I am very new to QGIS. I am working from work so there is extra security which is why I think I have problems accessing OpenLayers plugins. The only one that seems to load is Google Maps. Google maps has too many features. I really just need the outlines to some northwest states.  Ideas? recommendations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Cartographic Boundary Shapefiles](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html) should be what you want and they should load faster than a web-based layer. Also you can delete any states you don't want.

There is also the [Tiger/Line Shapefile database](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php) you can choose which products you want to download.

Since you are new to QGIS the steps would be to 1) download and extract the files 2) [add the .shp file as a layer in QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html) by pressing Ctrl+Shift+V and browsing to the file.